# Is there a way to find out how long a body will glide after a force is applied once?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, friction, inertia

Can you tell how long a body will retain it's motion after being given a push from x amount of force (ex. 15 force applied, motion will last 18 seconds)?

Comment: Newton's first law says that the body will keep moving unless it is in turn acted upon by an external force. Therefore, this is only possible if you know something about the force slowing the object down (e.g. friction, air resistance or collision with the ground)

Comment: @G.Lang what if a do have the air resistance/friction can I figure out how much of an opposing force to apply onto my body to stop it completely?

Answer (score 1):

If a force $F$ is applied to an object of mass $m$ for time $t$ then it does work $\frac {F^2t^2}{2m}$ on the object. If we assume the frictional forces $F_f$ that slow down the object are independent of its speed (which is approximately true for kinetic friction, but less true for air resistance) then the work done over a distance $d$ by friction is $F_fd$. So the distance that the object travels before it comes to rest is

$$d_{max} = \frac {F^2t^2}{2F_fm}$$

so $d_{max} \propto  t^2$. In other words, if the object travels $10$ metres when a force is applied to it for $1$ second, then applying the same force to it for $2$ seconds will make it travel $4$ times as far i.e. $40$ metres.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the object should never stop moving unless some sort of external obstruction is presented.
But in real life the object still stops moving after some time. This is because of the 'external obstructions' present in the form of friction, air resistance or something similar.